# Webpage copy and paste alternate content

Tags: css, copy-paste, uppercase

I just discovered a funny thing about copy and paste.

Go to Diablo 3's website (http://us.battle.net/en/) and navigate to the bottom, you can see:

> ©2012 Blizzard Entertainment, Inc. All rights reserved

It is all upper-case text in the webpage, but after I copy and paste,
it's automatically converted to camel case. How can this be done? Is it done through CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's just CSS. Specifically `text-transform:uppercase`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="copyright">&copy;2012 Blizzard Entertainment, Inc.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#copyright {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```